How to measure Statistical Significance for calculated Sensitivity, Specificity, Precision, Accuracy and f1 values?
I am trying to understand how to calculate one or more measures of statistical significance to display alongside metrics I've calculated from my data.
Abbreviations I am using in the rest of this post:

TP = true positives (total count)
TN = true negatives (total count)
FP = false positives (total count)
FN = false negatives (total count)

I have a dataset comprised of pairs of results where one result is the Ground Truth and the other is algorithmically generated. From these, I have calculated the following metrics:

Accuracy = (TN+TP)/(TN+TP+FN+FP)
Specificity = (TN)/(TN+FP)
Sensitivity or Recall = (TP)/(TP+FN)
Precision = (TP)/(TP+FP)
F1 = (2 * Precision * Sensitivity or Recall) / (Precision + Sensitivity or Recall)

Each of these gives a number in the range $[0-1]$, or nothing when the data doesn't allow to calculate it (e.g. if TP + FP = $0$, precision can't be calculated).
Of course the numbers are more meaningful when more datasets have been used to calculate them. If I calculated accuracy to be $0.9$ using $5$ datasets, that tells me very little, but if I calculated it using $5000$ datasets, that is a more useful number.
I was hoping to display the $p$-value alongside the number, but I am not sure how to calculate it. If I understand the "meaning" of $p$-value correctly, it is the probability that I would get the same values for these metrics if I swapped out the algorithm I got my results from with an algorithm which returns completely random output.
So, with infinite time and processing power, I could run a Monte Carlo simulation with a random algorithm and compare it to my ground truth data, until I get the same metrics, and calculate the $p$-value from the ratio of the simulations that successfully reached the same metric numbers vs those simulations that didn't. (This is of course not feasible in reality)
Is there any statistical significance measure that could work in this case?

Things like a chi-squared test (possibly with Yates's correction) or Fisher's exact test may give you a $p$-value related to whether your algorithm performed better than something random.  But it is not clear to me whether this is what you are asking about rather than confidence intervals for your statistics/metrics.

I'm not sure why you would want a p value for these statistics. But if you did want one, you would need to formulate a null hypothesis for each. I have rarely (if ever) seen p values for these -- I can't recall seeing one, but I may have seen them somewhere.

When you say "datasets" (5 vs. 5000), you probably mean "datapoints", or "observations" (a dataset is basically a sample, i.e. a "set" of data). You may want to edit your question accordingly. Also, p-values are normally not used for such statistics; instead one uses confidence intervals (which are flipped p-values).  See e.g. http://vassarstats.net/clin1.html, which will compute the CI's for you.
